# how to organize the code?

Tags: php

```
<?php
if(arg(0)=="test"){
echo "code here";
}else{
echo '<div class="item-list">
  <?php if (!empty($title)) : ?>
    <h3><?php print $title; ?></h3>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <<?php print $options['type']; ?>>
    <?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
      <li class="<?php print $classes[$id]; ?>"><?php print $row; ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </<?php print $options['type']; ?>>
</div>
';}
```

the else echo is too long. is there a way to make it small.

Comment: you're writing a php code with your script?

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, this is bad code. You are messing business logic with views. I would definitely use a very simple template system like :

[Simple and Fast Template Engine](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/beyond-template-engine)

This code cannot be maintained and if it gets bigger, it would be a hell to even read. Please do yourself a favor and separate logic from views.

Take a look at this nice example from the url above, to see how code should be organized :

```
<?php    
require_once('template.php');    

$tpl = & new Template('./templates/');    
$tpl->set('title', 'User Profile');    

$profile = array(    
   'name' => 'Frank',    
   'email' => 'frank@bob.com',    
   'password' => 'ultra_secret'    
);    

$tpl->set_vars($profile);    

echo $tpl->fetch('profile.tpl.php');    
?>

The associated template looks like this:

<table cellpadding="3" border="0" cellspacing="1">    
   <tr>    
       <td>Name</td>    
       <td><?=$name;?></td>    
   </tr>    
   <tr>    
       <td>Email</td>    
       <td><?=$email;?></td>    
   </tr>    
   <tr>    
       <td>Password</td>    
       <td><?=$password;?></td>    
   </tr>    
</table>

And the parsed output is as follows:

<table cellpadding="3" border="0" cellspacing="1">    
 <tr>    
   <td>Name</td>    
   <td>Frank</td>    
 </tr>    
 <tr>    
   <td>Email</td>    
   <td>frank@bob.com</td>    
 </tr>    
 <tr>    
   <td>Password</td>    
   <td>ultra_secret</td>    
 </tr>    
</table>
```

Comment: his code's messy, for sure, but i'm not really seeing the "messing business logic within views;" even the most mundane view can have a foreach loop within it.

Comment: Ryan, when i answered his question, the code sample was different. He edited it. And you're right, as it is now.

Comment: Ah, I see! I love MVC as much as the next guy, but thought this was a little extreme :) all clear now.

Comment: I love it as well, being a Rails guy also :D

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised that code would even run. Here's a better way, without using echo: just close the php interpreter while you generate your html output.

```
<?php
if(arg(0)=="test"){
echo "code here";
}else{
?>
<div class="item-list">
  <?php if (!empty($title)) : ?>
    <h3><?php print $title; ?></h3>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <<?php print $options['type']; ?>>
    <?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
      <li class="<?php print $classes[$id]; ?>"><?php print $row; ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </<?php print $options['type']; ?>>
</div>
<?
}
?>
```

Comment: i feel the last should write as this <?php
echo '}';
?>  am i right?

Comment: whenever you call `echo` in php, it typically outputs a string, _NOT_ PHP code; so you'd definitely want `<? } ?>` (which is PHP code that ends the `else` statement) rather than `<? echo '}'; ?>` which would just put the string } into your HTML source.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$output = "<div class='item-list'>";
if(!empty($title)) $output .= "<h3>".$title."</h3>";
$output .= $options['type'];
foreach($rows as $id => $row) {
    $output .= '<li class="' . $classes[$id] . '">' . $row . '</li>';
}
$ouput .= $options['type'] . "</div>";

$output = (arg(0) == "test" ? "code here" : $output);
echo $output;

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks nicer if you don't switch between PHP and HTML context (also indentation *does* help):

```
<?php
   if (arg(0)=="test") {
      echo "code here";
   }
   else {
      echo '<div class="item-list">'
         . @$title
         . "<$options[type]>";

      foreach ($rows as $id => $row) {
          print "<li class=\"{$classes[$id]}\">$row</li>";
      }

      echo "</$options[type]>";
  }
```

Comment: what's worse: php within html, or html within php?

Comment: id be willing to bet a vast majority of php developers would disagree with this.

Comment: @Galen: No, I think it's mostly just WP coders and newcomers who hate indentation.

Comment: echoing html is as ugly as you can get